# How do I install previous version of SciKit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, download

Right now I am having an error display:

> D:\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:334: UserWarning: Trying
>   to unpickle estimator ExtraTreeClassifier from version 0.22.2.post1
>   when using version 0.23.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid
>   results. Use at your own risk.

Because I am using 0.23.1 of Scikit. I've checked on their website and found the version 0.22.2 but I can't figure out how to install it? I even see the GitHub could I download the files from there? Not sure how that works.

This is the link for 0.22.2 
https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First uninstall the currently installed scikit-learn with the command:
`pip uninstall scikit-learn`

And then install the 0.22.2 version with the command:
`pip install scikit-learn==0.22.2`

Answer (score 0):

Please type:

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.22.2
```

in your terminal. I just tested it and it works. :)